# Did Joe Dempsie make a cameo appearance in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter

There's a scene of a wizard reading "*A Brief History of Time*" in the movie, *Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkaban*. The wizard looks like Joe Dempsie.

Here is a snippet of Game of Thrones season two that show Joe Dempsie as Gendry.

<sup>Still for easier comparison</sup>
[image]

But his filmography list does not mention any Harry Potter movies, and nor does his IMDB page.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Dempsie
- https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1478079/

If he were in the movie, he would have been 16 or 17 years old when it was filmed.

Is there any evidence to suggest that the wizard reading "A Brief History of Time" is Joe Dempsie?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've never thought of Joe Dempsie being that wizard (just because I can't see any similar facial characteristics), and I originally found that information on a [Harry Potter fandom](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ian_Brown): it's Ian Brown.

He's also pictured as this wizard on his [IMDB page](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1497594/) and credits :

[image: Ian Brown IMDB page]

*From comments*
For those unaware, Ian Brown is not an actor. He was lead vocalist with a band from the late 80s/early 90s, [The Stone Roses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stone_Roses), who were a major influence on a lot of the Brit Pop movement of the 90s. This music scene in the UK was known as "Madchester", a portmanteau of Manchester, the city many of these bands originated, & a local term for 'I really like this', "I'm mad for it".
By a series of coincidences, Brown knew a girl who knew the director… & it happened that Daniel Radcliffe was a fan, so he managed to 'blag'* a cameo.
Possibly because they shared a music scene, a fashion style, a geographical & musical origin …& also knew each other well, Ian Brown could often be mistaken for Liam Gallagher from Oasis -

[image]

**Blagging*, in the UK , especially inside the music or film industry, is not to gain something by deception, but to gain entry to somewhere or something you wouldn't ordinarily be invited to by 'knowing someone who knows someone who can get you through the door'. The US equivalent may be 'schmoozing'.

Culturally, you could consider The Stone Roses to be as important to the history of music in the UK as Nirvana were in the US.

Comment: All those Manchester bands of the era share a similar set of gestures & facial expressions;) At first glance I thought it was a Gallagher, but yup, you're absolutely right, it's a 'stone rose'. I'd honestly never have noticed.

Comment: Never thought of a Gallagher but thinking twice...

Comment: Like peas in a pod - I thought a picture of the two of them together wouldn't be too hard to find… https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRulS.png

Comment: Ha!  I was right!  It was Ian Brown!

Comment: @steelersquirrel: you're 7 hours late, I think you should have used 2 twists on your time-turner :)

Comment: It might be worth adding a little about who Ian Brown is - Stone Roses, Madchester scene, potential confusion with Liam, Oasis etc… just for those either too young or not British, who may not be aware of that whole musical movement from the 90s; the fact that Radcliffe was a fan, Brown knew the director [indirectly] & why this therefore becomes a cameo, not an 'extra' in the scene. [I could do it, but I don't like the idea of adding so much 'metadata' to someone else's answer unilaterally]

Comment: @Tetsujin : I don't mind adding those facts, but I've not enough time right now. Feel free to do so :)

Comment: I had a go - tried to keep it light & 'chummy'. Feel free to edit further. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin: as you could say after such a tribute to movies, music (last play of the movie) and musician, and also such an edit: "*Mischief Managed!*" :)

Comment: @OldPadawan No worries.  I didn't have the time to put an answer together :)